# How to use len() to create an equal-length string full of asterisks?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random, string-length

My assignment is to create a game of Hangman. I'm trying to turn `"Someword"` into `"********"` to display it to the player, but my code returns one asterisk too many for any given input.

The following is the text file I'm reading the words from:

```
PYTHON
SOMETHING
COMPLETELY
DIFFERENT
```

(it continues for many lines)

Here's my code:

```
import random

def diction(random):

    lives = 5
    DICTIONARY = {"secretWord" : random, "lives" : lives}
    guess = len(DICTIONARY["secretWord"]) * "*"
    print (DICTIONARY["secretWord"])
    print (guess)


file = input("Please insert file name: ")

f = open(file)
content = f.readlines()
f.close()

random = (random.choice(content))
random = random.replace(" ", "")


diction(random)
```

I'm expecting output of (for example)

```
PYTHON
******
```

and instead getting output of

```
PYTHON
*******
```

Comment: Which version on Python do you use, Python 2.x or Python 3.x?

Comment: I have the Python 3.x version

Comment: readlines() keeps the `\n` newline character that ends each line; thus every count will have one character too many.

Comment: Thank you! Editing the replace function I had to 'random = random.replace("\n", "")' fixed the problem. Much love!

Comment: You also shadow builtin variables. `random =` kills future access to the `random` module. `file =` kills future access to things like `file.close`. The names are terrible too: uppercase `DICTIONARY` would be better as 'secret = {`, `file` could be `filename` and `random =` would read much better as `secret_word =`

Comment: @msw Thankyou for the help! I'm fairly new to Python so I am still trying to get the hang of it all, I have now edited it and given the arguments better variables, thank you again!

Comment: @SeanBrackenborough I edited your question rather extensively to make it easier to follow. I also rolled back the changes you made to your code that resolved the issue at hand. It's no use to future readers having the same issue if the code in the question doesn't create the problem you describe! That's what answers are for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `file.readlines` leaves the trailing newline character, so a file like

```
foo
bar
spam
eggs
```

becomes

```
['foo\n','bar\n','spam\n','eggs\n']
```

The solution is to use `str.strip` (or `str.rstrip` if you anticipate having leading whitespace) on each element. For instance:

```
words = map(str.strip, some_file.readlines())
# in Python3, you should call list(map(str.strip, some_file.readlines()))
secret_word = random.choice(words)
```

Or else just strip the word you need and ignore the rest.

```
words = some_file.readlines()
secret_word = random.choice(words).strip()
```